# Springboot application with 3rd Party API

Tags: api, spring-boot

I'm new to spring boot and want to build an application using a REST third party API, but I'm not sure how to go about it as I can't seem to find any tutorials online that use a third party api.

Comment: Could you explain by what you mean by a third party API and what one you have in mind?

Comment: A third party API such as the NASA api/star wars api/ one that gives you the weather. In my mind I don't mind using any of them.

I just want to do something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is your intention to consume a REST API within your spring boot application then you should look at the Spring RestTemplate.

Here is a [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/).

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer by @Dean, I would suggest if you are looking to build a quick integration with 3rd party API, you should also check [Spring Cloud Open Feign](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/reference/html/) project. It generates API clients for you, so you need not worry about writing RestTemplates by yourself.